# jquery response is correct but picked up wrong

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there any idea why the code below keeps alerting as **wrong** although the response comes back as **hello**?

It should alert as **correct**!

Tnanks

**JQUERY**

```
var term = 'jan';

$.ajax(
{
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'process.php',
    data : 'term=' + term,
    dataType  : 'text',
    timeout   : 600000,
    success   : function(response)
    {
        if (response == 'hello')
        {
            alert('Correct');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Wrong');
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST['term'] == 'jan')
{
    echo 'hello';
}
else
{
    echo 'noooo';
}
```

Comment: try to inspect the response and be sure you have no extra trailing spaces. what if you add a `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Have you tried `alert(response)` then try `alert(response.length)` and check it equals 5, if not there is likely whitespace, perhaps `response.trim() == 'hello'` will help

Comment: Just do `console.log(response)` and see what you're getting backing, or try `if ($.trim(response) == 'hello') {....}`, you likely have spaces in your PHP file.

Comment: When building an AJAX app, an invaluable tool is a debugger such as FireBug for Firefox, it can show you the response you are getting back and allow you to set breakpoints in your code and read values. Highly recommended. Chrome has a built in debugger, as does later versions of IE.

Comment: $.trim(response) solved. Thanks

Comment: That's good. I have added an answer so people know it was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely whitespace in your return result. This can be solved by trimming the return result

```
var term = 'jan';

$.ajax(
{
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'process.php',
    data : 'term=' + term,
    dataType  : 'text',
    timeout   : 600000,
    success   : function(response)
    {
        if (response.trim() == 'hello')
        {
            alert('Correct');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Wrong');
        }
    }
});
```